# Logo in a LaTeX header, Koma-Script letter class

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, koma-script

I use this class definition in the preamble of my document:

```
\documentclass[template, 
           backaddress=off, 
           foldmarks=false, 
           enlargefirstpage,
           pagenumber=off,
           parskip=half
           ]{scrlttr2}
```

I set the header with logo on the left and information on the right like this:

```
\firsthead{ 
\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\raggedleft{ 
\rlap{\usekomavar{fromlogo}}
  \addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\fontsize{12}{17}\selectfont\scshape \usekomavar{fromname}\\[3mm]
     \fontsize{11}{11}\selectfont\scshape \usekomavar{position} \\ \usekomavar{department}
     }%
   }% 
}%
```

Yet the logo and return address are not aligned. In any other class I could use the `fancyhdr` package to specify left and right head like this:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{1cm}
\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
\fancyhead[L]{ % left
\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\fontsize{12}{17}\selectfont\scshape
\usekomavar{fromname}\\[3mm]
    \fontsize{11}{11}\selectfont\scshape \usekomavar{position} \\
\usekomavar{department}
}
 \fancyhead[R]{ % right
 \includegraphics[width=4cm]{kuleuven_zwart.eps}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

yet this won't work for the `letter` class. How can I achieve something similar?

---

Template code:

```
\ProvidesFile{template.lco}

\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper, textwidth=17cm, textheight=22cm, marginparsep=16cm, marginparwidth=1cm}

\newkomavar{department}
\newkomavar{position}
\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{kuleuven_zwart.eps}}

% ===  FORMATTING STUFF
\@setplength{backaddrheight}{0cm}

% shift the page body on the left to make room for data and logo
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{\useplength{toaddrhpos}}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1in}
\l@addto@macro{\@typearea@end}{
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{\useplength{toaddrhpos}}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1in}
}%

%set the font size and leading
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{10.0}{17}\selectfont}

% === HEADER DEFINITION
\firsthead{ 

 \parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\raggedleft{ 

    \rlap{\usekomavar{fromlogo}}

      \addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\fontsize{12}{17}\selectfont\scshape \usekomavar{fromname}\\[5mm]
         \fontsize{11}{11}\selectfont\scshape \usekomavar{position} \\ \usekomavar{department}

    }%
  }%

}%

\endinput
```

Document:

```
\documentclass[template, 
               backaddress=off, 
               foldmarks=false, 
               pagenumber=off,
               ]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{lipsum}   

\setkomavar{fromname}{this}
\setkomavar{position}{is not}
\setkomavar{department}{aligned}
\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{%
       Yeti\\%
      from Himalayah\\%
}

\opening{Dear,}

\lipsum

\closing{Regards,}


\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use two `\parbox`es (one for the logo and the other one for the information on the right), and the `\adjustbox` commad from the adjust box package to control the vertical alignment with respect to the logo; also beware of superfluous blank spaces:

```
\ProvidesFile{template.lco}

\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\geometry{a4paper, textwidth=17cm, textheight=22cm, marginparsep=16cm, marginparwidth=1cm}

\newkomavar{department}
\newkomavar{position}
\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{kuleuven_zwart.eps}}}

% ===  FORMATTING STUFF
\@setplength{backaddrheight}{0cm}

% shift the page body on the left to make room for data and logo
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{\useplength{toaddrhpos}}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1in}
\l@addto@macro{\@typearea@end}{
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{\useplength{toaddrhpos}}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1in}
}%

%set the font size and leading
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{10.0}{17}\selectfont}

% === HEADER DEFINITION
\firsthead{% 
 \parbox[t]{0.5\textwidth}{% 
    \usekomavar{fromlogo}}\parbox[t]{0.5\textwidth}{\raggedleft{
      \addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\fontsize{12}{17}\selectfont\scshape \usekomavar{fromname}\\[5mm]
         \fontsize{11}{11}\selectfont\scshape \usekomavar{position} \\ \usekomavar{department}%
    }%
  }%
}%

\endinput
```

Here's a partial image of the result of your example code, using the CTAN lion (drawing by Duane Bibby) as image:

[image]