# Package sclrttr2: How do I use the fromlogo-variable? How do I get a footer on the 2nd page?

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, header-footer, positioning, koma-script

I am using `scrlttr2` for a formal letter template. I am facing 3 problems:

---

### (1) Logo in the header of the 1st page

I want a header logo on the first page in the top right corner **above the header line**, as shown on the following image:
[image: This is how it should look like.]

This is the way it looks now (the wrong way):
[image: This is how it looks now.]

---

### (2) Logo in the footer of ALL pages

- I want the same logo in the footer as well and **on the first and on all other pages**. It has to look like that:
  [image: This is how it should look like.]

Now it looks like that (the wrong way):
[image]

---

### (3) Logo in the header on all following pages

On all following pages, I want the logo to be still there, but without the contact details. It has to look like that:
[image]

Now it's just empty.

---

That's the code I used now:

```
\documentclass%%
  [fontsize=11pt,
   parskip=half,%%
   fromalign=right,%%
   fromphone=on,%%
   fromfax=on,%%
   fromrule=aftername,%%
   fromemail=on,%%  
   fromlogo=true,%%
   foldmarks=false,%%
   firstfoot=true,%%
   subject=titled,%%
   pagenumber=botright,%%
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{selinput}
\usepackage{newcent}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\SelectInputMappings{
  adieresis={ä},
  germandbls={ß},
  Euro={€},
}

\setkomafont{fromname}{\scshape \LARGE}
\setkomafont{backaddress}{\mdseries}

\makeatletter
\@setplength{firstheadvpos}{7mm}
\@setplength{firstfootvpos}{265mm}%%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setkomavar{fromaddress}{
    my surname name\\
    my streetname 21\\
    my example city}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+99\,(9)999)\,999\,999\,99}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+99\,(9)999)\,999\,999\,99}
\setkomavar{fromfax}{+99\,(9)999)\,999\,999\,99}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{name@email-address.com}
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{ - }
\setkomavar{place}{city}
\setkomavar{signature}{example signature}
\setkomavar{frombank}{IBAN: 9999\,9999\,9999\,9999\,9999\,99\\
  BIC: 12341234ABDC\\
  example example example\vspace{0.1cm}\\
  example example example example\\
  example example example, example example example}
\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\includegraphics[scale=.2]{/home/philipp/Dropbox/briefvorlage_example_TechExchange/generic_logo.pdf}}

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\footnotesize%
  \rule[5pt]{472pt}{.3pt}\\
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}% 
    \usekomavar{fromname}\\
    \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
  \end{tabular}%
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
    \usekomavar{fromphone}\\
    \usekomavar{fromfax}\\
    \usekomavar{fromemail}\\
  \end{tabular}%
  \ifkomavarempty{frombank}{}{%
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
      \usekomavar{frombank}
    \end{tabular}%
    }%
}%

\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\enclname}{Anlagen}

\begin{letter}{Mr.\\surname name\\office\\street name\\postal code and city}\vspace{0.3cm}

\setkomavar{subject}{subject: example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example}

\opening{Dear Mr. xxxxx xxxxxxxxxx,}

\lipsum[1-4]

\closing{Regards,}
\setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Enclosure(s):}

\encl{example enclosure}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

I was researching for several hours but without any success. These were the most useful posts I checked, unfortunately without any success: [Logo in Briefkopf platzieren (place logo in header)](https://komascript.de/node/1530), [Logo in a LaTeX header, Koma-Script letter class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/logo-in-a-latex-header-koma-script-letter-class), [Header and Footer does not show on second page (scrlttr2)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289076/header-and-footer-does-not-show-on-second-page-scrlttr2).

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

To solve the three problems you can do:

1. Logo in the header of the 1st page: to get the logo above the line, followed by the adress etc. the imho best way is to define an own `firsthead` like this:

   ```
   \setkomavar{firsthead}{\raggedleft % <==================================
     \usekomavar{fromlogo}\\[+1cm]
     \rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}\\
     \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
     \usekomavar{fromphone}\\
     \usekomavar{fromfax}\\
     \usekomavar{fromemail}\\% <===========================================
   }
   ```

   To activate this definition call the option `firsthead=true,` as class option.
2. Logo in the footer of ALL pages: First you have to add the logo to the `firstfoot` like this:

   ```
   \setkomavar{firstfoot}{\footnotesize%
     \rule[5pt]{472pt}{.3pt}\\
     \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}% 
       \includegraphics[scale=.3]{generic-logo-company}\\[-5mm] % <==================
       \usekomavar{fromname}\\
       \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
     \end{tabular}%
     \hfill
     \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
       \usekomavar{fromphone}\\
       \usekomavar{fromfax}\\
       \usekomavar{fromemail}\\
     \end{tabular}%
     \ifkomavarempty{frombank}{}{%
       \hfill
       \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
         \usekomavar{frombank}
       \end{tabular}%
       }%
   }%
   ```

   Then you need to define the `nextfoot` like this:

   ```
   % nextfoot nexthead
   \setkomavar{nextfoot}{\hspace{-1.1cm}\parbox[b]{472pt}{\usekomavar{firstfoot}}}% <=======================
   ```
3. Logo in the header on all following pages: To get the line and the logo to the header you call the class option `headsepline=true,` and add the following code

   ```
   \pagestyle{myheadings}
   \markboth{}{\protect\includegraphics[scale=.3]{generic-logo-company}}
   ```

Then you get the following complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
  fontsize=11pt,
  parskip=half,%%
% fromalign=right,% right,locationright %% <============================
  firsthead=true, % <===================================================
  fromphone=on,%%
  fromfax=on,%%
  fromrule=aftername,%%
  fromemail=on,%%  
  fromlogo=true,%%
  foldmarks=false,%%
  firstfoot=true,%%
  subject=titled,%%
  pagenumber=botright,%%
  headsepline=true, % <=================================================
  DIN
]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{newcent}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{
  adieresis={ä},
  germandbls={ß},
  Euro={€},
}

\setkomafont{fromname}{\scshape \LARGE}
\setkomafont{backaddress}{\mdseries}

\makeatletter
\@setplength{firstheadvpos}{7mm}
\@setplength{firstfootvpos}{265mm}%%
\makeatother
\setkomavar{firsthead}{\raggedleft % <==================================
  \usekomavar{fromlogo}\\[+1cm]
  \rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}\\
  \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
  \usekomavar{fromphone}\\
  \usekomavar{fromfax}\\
  \usekomavar{fromemail}\\% <===========================================
}


\begin{document}

\setkomavar{fromaddress}{
    my surname name\\
    my streetname 21\\
    my example city}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+99\,(9)999)\,999\,999\,99}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+99\,(9)999)\,999\,999\,99}
\setkomavar{fromfax}{+99\,(9)999)\,999\,999\,99}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{name@email-address.com}
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{ - }
\setkomavar{place}{city}
\setkomavar{signature}{example signature}
\setkomavar{frombank}{IBAN: 9999\,9999\,9999\,9999\,9999\,99\\
  BIC: 12341234ABDC\\
  example example example\vspace{0.1cm}\\
  example example example example\\
  example example example, example example example}
\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\includegraphics[scale=.5]{generic-logo-company}\vspace{-1.3cm}}

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markboth{}{\protect\includegraphics[scale=.3]{generic-logo-company}}

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\footnotesize%
  \rule[5pt]{472pt}{.3pt}\\
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}% 
    \includegraphics[scale=.3]{generic-logo-company}\\[-5mm] % <==================
    \usekomavar{fromname}\\
    \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
  \end{tabular}%
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
    \usekomavar{fromphone}\\
    \usekomavar{fromfax}\\
    \usekomavar{fromemail}\\
  \end{tabular}%
  \ifkomavarempty{frombank}{}{%
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
      \usekomavar{frombank}
    \end{tabular}%
    }%
}%

% nextfoot nexthead
\setkomavar{nextfoot}{\hspace{-1.1cm}\parbox[b]{472pt}{\usekomavar{firstfoot}}}% <=======================

\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\enclname}{Anlagen}

\begin{letter}{Mr.\\surname name\\office\\street name\\postal code and city}\vspace{0.3cm}

\setkomavar{subject}{subject: example example example example example 
  example example example example example example example example 
  example example example example example example example example 
  example example example}

\opening{Dear Mr. xxxxx xxxxxxxxxx,}

\lipsum[1-8]

\closing{Regards,}
\setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Enclosure(s)}

\encl{example enclosure}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

with the following resulting pages:

[image: first page]

and page 2:

[image: page 2]

BTW: in german letters the leading `Betrifft:` is not longer used ...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a start that may help.

1. For logo above address use `fromalign=locationright` instead of `\fromalign=right`.  I found this required adding some vertical negative space after the logo itself which I have inserted in the `fromlogo`.  You also need to adjust the `loc...` variables to position this block.
2. For logo in the footer just use an appropriate includegraphics where you want it
3. For logo in the running head to the right, choose pagestyle `headings` and `\markboth{}{logo code}`.  For the rule under this add `headsepline=true` to the class options.

This gives

[image: Sample head]

[image: First page foot]

[image: Running head]

```
\documentclass%%
  [fontsize=11pt,
   parskip=half,%%
   fromalign=locationright,%%
   fromphone=on,%%
   fromfax=on,%%
   fromrule=aftername,%%
   fromemail=on,%%
   fromlogo=true,%%
   foldmarks=false,%%
   firstfoot=true,%%
   subject=titled,%%
   pagenumber=botright,%%
   headsepline=true
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{selinput}
\usepackage{newcent}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\SelectInputMappings{
  adieresis={ä},
  germandbls={ß},
  Euro={€},
}

\setkomafont{fromname}{\scshape \LARGE}
\setkomafont{backaddress}{\mdseries}


\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\@setplength{locheight}{58mm}
\@setplength{locwidth}{50mm}
\@setplength{locvpos}{10mm}
\@setplength{toaddrvpos}{24mm}
\@setplength{firstfootvpos}{265mm}%%
\makeatother

\setkomavar{fromaddress}{%
    my surname name\\
    my streetname 21\\
    my example city}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+99\,(9)\,999\,999\,99}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+99\,(9)\,999\,999\,99}
\setkomavar{fromfax}{+99\,(9)\,999\,999\,99}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{name@email-address.com}
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{ - }
\setkomavar{place}{city}
\setkomavar{signature}{example signature}
\setkomavar{frombank}{IBAN: 9999\,9999\,9999\,9999\,9999\,99\\
  BIC: 12341234ABDC\\
  example example example\vspace{0.1cm}\\
  example example example example\\
  example example example, example example example}
\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\includegraphics[scale=.2]{example-image-a}\vspace{-1cm}}

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markboth{}{\protect\includegraphics[scale=.1]{example-image-a}}

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\footnotesize%
  \rule[5pt]{472pt}{.3pt}\\
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
    \includegraphics[scale=.05]{example-image-a}\\[-5mm]
    \usekomavar{fromname}\\
    \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
  \end{tabular}%
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
    \usekomavar{fromphone}\\
    \usekomavar{fromfax}\\
    \usekomavar{fromemail}\\
  \end{tabular}%
  \ifkomavarempty{frombank}{}{%
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
      \usekomavar{frombank}
    \end{tabular}%
    }%
}%

\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\enclname}{Anlagen}

\begin{letter}{Mr.\\surname name\\office\\street name\\postal code and city}\vspace{0.3cm}

\setkomavar{subject}{subject: example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example}

\opening{Dear Mr. xxxxx xxxxxxxxxx,}

\lipsum[1-4]

\closing{Regards,}
\setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Enclosure(s):}

\encl{example enclosure}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```